Could time (in the sense of a labor-hour) be a stable commodity base for a currency on the modern city-state level?
Commodity currencies were the standard for most of history. Coins were made out of precious metals like gold or silver. Later on paper currency was exchangeable for a certain amount of gold or silver or some other precious commodity. In the late 20th Century, almost every nation has switched to the fiat currency system, where money is only backed by the trust in government.
I have been doing research on time-based currencies. These are effectively currencies where the base of the monetary system isn't a resource or trust, but time.
Specifically, a set duration of unskilled labor. Banknotes will represent the amount of basic unskilled labor (fast food cashier, dishwashing, basic cleaning, fruit-picking, etc.) that a person can exchange their money for. The denominations of the currency will be the same as time (hours, minutes,seconds,days,weeks,months, etc.). Jobs that require more skills or are more valuable than a basic job for other reasons charge more by the hour (e.g. 1  hour by an MLB Rookie used to perform baseball-tasks are worth 40 hour chits).
Unlike other commodity currencies, a time-based currency isn't directly affected by the location or availability of resources. Humanity's labor duration also can't run out the same way gold or oil can. This should help it avoid some (but not all) of the downfalls for a commodity currency in post-industrial societies.
There have been real-life examples of a time-based currency, but they have only been performed either by a single company or by a small self-sustaining commune where everyone knows each other. Could a large modern city-state (like Hong Kong) run an entire economy using a time-based currency without massive inefficiencies or socioeconomic problems? Or is a commodity like this only viable in societies that are very small or much less advanced?

You seem to be referring to indentured servitude - in all but name. Short-term contracts. Is that right?

"Unlike other commodity currencies, a time-based currency isn't directly affected by the location or availability of resources." - absolutely incorrect, there are places and times where labour is plentiful and others where it is rare, hence business reporting on the job market.  "Humanity's labor duration also can't run out the same way gold or oil can." - yes, it can, many places have an ageing population where there is less work-time available than there was previously.  The fundamental assumptions behind the question are flawed.

@KerrAVon2055 I meant more in the sense that unlike a gold mine or oil field, humans can move around anywhere and live almost anywhere on Earth. An Aging population could drive up the price of labor, but creating more young people is easier than finding more gold or more oil.

@Rhymehouse no, they can't move around anywhere with equal ease and cost which is why fly-in fly-out workers at mines (and other industries) get paid much more than people doing the equivalent work in proximity to cities and towns.  The same labour is much more valuable in places it is less pleasant to live.  Availability of labour and it's value vary with population, technology and other trends.

??? Ordinary real life money can be exchanged for labor. As for the assertion that the price of labor "isn't directly affected by the location or availability of resources", this is in direct contradiction with reality. Hiring a man to dig a ditch in Bengal will cost you very much less than in Rhineland-Palatinate.

The problem with this is that the labour-hours of two different unskilled labourers may very easily be considerably different in terms of work achieved.

This question is similar to: Post Scarcity Currency. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What you're describing is money. It's using different terms, but the underlying mechanics are the same. Including the risk of inflation and the need for trust (your time credits only have value if someone is willing to trade for them).

Time is money, isn't it?

Socialists tried this during the 1930s Spanish Civil war: https://youtu.be/ozDbGAuUvgE?si=KiT2M3lal6nHZZfz&t=426

@MontyWild more importanly diffrent is value, a hour digging out a septic tank will have ot pay a LOT more than an hour digging holes in a feild. both are unskilled but have vast diffrences in desirablity.


A fiat currency with a fancy name.
While assorted nutcases tend to rail against it, a modern economy desperately needs a fiat currency managed by a national bank ... theirs or that of another major global economy. (For little states with untrusted institutions, both options may be viable. Big states need their own.) Contrary to your thoughts, the human labor pool does change if one looks at able-bodied workers as a proportion of the population. And it does change in ways which are bad for economic planning. Say there are few children born, and many workers will retire soon. Then I expect the value of my cash to go up in the future. The smart idea would be to stash it in a safe, not invest it in a factory. Smart for me, bad for the economy, that is.
To resolve this, you need a central bank managing the issue of chits.

A minimum wage and right-to-a-job with a fancy name.
Would a random person with a debt of 8 hour-chits have the right to repay that debt with one working day of unskilled labor? What if the creditor doesn't need unskilled labor right now? What if the person has an injured arm, and doesn't manage to do much in that day? Would there be an institution where people can check in, do their hours, and collect chits? Those jobs would have to be standardized, unskilled, and not dirty, dangerous, or demeaning to make them one-chit-per-hour jobs. How many of those are there?

Variant: Crypto-currency mining with a fancy name.
Say you can get one hour-chit by turning up at the municipal office and doing work for one hour. That chit is then in circulation. Other people may or may not do the same, but the amount of chits in circulation rises and the exchange value of each chit drops, unless (a) the value of the economy happens to rise in proportion (we're back to fiat currency) or (b) someone removes chits from circulation. If the government or central bank does the latter, that needs to be tax-funded ...


A mix of the two
Once upon a time, a chit used to be one day in the fields, swinging a sickle (that was before fancy scythes were introduced). Those rules have never been repealed, and one can repay a debt by mowing the creditors' lawn, but the ratios are so absurd that nobody really does that. The actual value is managed as fiat currency.



'Unskilled' labour isn't unskilled
There's enormous variation in how fast or effectively you do various tasks. A skilled fast food cashier might reliably upsell products or handle orders efficiently, a more skilled cleaner might clean several times as fast.
As such, it's not an especially universal measurement of value. It would mean the value of common goods would be hotly contested and would vary massively depending on how much you trusted your local labourers. That would add massive inefficiencies to the value of any product.
Labor theory of value is incorrect
People's valuing of various goods is also based off subjective factors. They might like certain workers more or certain luxuries more regardless of the hours needed to make them. As such, under your system people's real valuing of purchases would be unrelated to the money.

Nitpick: I think you might be conflating skill and efficiency.  If two guys are mopping rooms and A takes three minutes while B takes 30 seconds, that doesn't make B more skilled. He's just doing the job more efficiently.

@elemtilas, isn't doing the job more efficiently a valuable skill? Unskilled labor is often used as a category to set it apart from formal professional certification, but that simply means some practitioners have managed to organize and some do not.

@o.m. -- Depends! I can mop a 20x20 floor in half a minute. That doesn't make me "skilled". It just means I use the mop and my body more efficiently that Three Minute Tommy. I sure as hell am not going to do any more work than him -- I'm gonna take a little break while he's mopping himself into a corner. I don't know any more than Tommy about the cleaning chemicals or the fancy floor scrubbing cart they use in the next building over. In this case, efficiency is a "skill" that could make me do more work for no more pay. After all, time is money! (c0nt)

(cont) I'd agree that efficiency is a skill when the currency is piecework! If me and Tommy both get paid one chit per floor mopped, I would be earning 6x his wage packet! Different currencies yield different motivations and different results. In this regard, the US$ is very much like the proposed time currency. People in low skilled work will tend to do the minimum work for the given pay. They're no motivation to do more. In fact, there is negative motivation, because if you do more, you don't get paid more. Professionals tend also to have incorporated within their education a (cont)

(cont) system of ethics and morals that unskilled labour lacks. Your nurse, your lawyer, your doctor. They all have some kind of ethical foundation that motivates them. They're less likely to work to the clock, less likely to shirk responsibility and more likely to work until the job is done properly.

@elemtilas, I think you and I have quite different views of so-called unskilled workers. Let's leave it at that.

@o.m. -- Fair enough!

@elemtilas To add to your point, your efficiency at "getting the floor mopped quickly" definitely does not mean that you are using a proper technique.  Back in highschool I worked at a Cuban restaurant, and while I started off as the guy who could finish the floor the fastest, the owner very rudely insulted my ma'ma for not teaching me the right way to mop a floor. Once I learned the right way to do it, I was no longer the fastest at it.

So I betcha Three Minute Tommy is actually skilled enough to properly sweep the floor first and mop with arcs that overlap each other so they don't miss spots... and that is a skill.

Don't use labor just use time itself.
X is how much one hour of a human life is worth (on average).
Terry pratchett tries a variant of this for a scifi setting, money is based on the time added to your life by life extending treatments, A year" being the most common standard measurment of pay. As in this peice of paper is worth one year added to your life. You could use somthing similir without the scifi stuff, this much money is worth 1 hour of your time, not labor just time as in this is what an hour of your life is worth. labor will will cost diffrent than this becasue diffrent labors have diffrent values, but the base of the money system is how much an hour of your life is worth.
Think of it as this is how much someone would have to pay you just for wasting an hour of your time before anything else is calculated, not labor just for consuming the time. It could even start by being based on the value placed on a human life, which averages around ~10 million dollars US. his number pops up a lot in insurance and legal matters. that would make an hour of your life worth about $15 US.

I think that labor will not work as a currency - the Nepene Nep's answer tells you exactly why: no two laborers do same work exactly the same.
Fiat currencies in use today aren't exactly just paper. They are, basically, a debt of one form of another, that's why they are in use. Very few have some functions of money of old time (USD, for example), but these are just vestiges at this point.
However, the concept of money being, at it's basic, a proxy for labor is not new nor wrong (NOTE: not talking about the Marx's Labor Theory of Value, which is basically POS).
That being said, I think you're approaching the problem from false premise: x-backed-currency being money, and using the former to substitute the latter as a medium of exchange in your brief history.
They aren't the same for the simplest reason: currency is currency and NOT money. This is the same difference as between number 4 and having four apples.
The biggest weakness of the currency is the ability to create it basically out of nothing (by fiat - though it's not exactly how that happens nowadays), and more so giving that ability to a institution of authority (usually a government), and this is why all fiat currencies always fail, without fail.
It can be argued that a market with currencies (because that's how that should work - multiple issuers) would not experience any "downfalls for a commodity currency in post-industrial societies", because even funny money has its uses.
I think that if you have to have some labor approximation in your currency system, it's better to base it on a value of an average single meal of a farm worker.

Let them pay taxes by time
The "Great Capitol Hill Baby Sitting Co-op" for example struggled and failed with it's attempt on a time-based currency.
You may want to read on it in Monetary Theory and the Great Capitol Hill Baby Sitting Co-op Crisis by Joan Sweeney and Richard James Sweeney
The main problem there was that people tended either to hoard the "money" (babysitting time) to be always able to go out or more people wanted to sit. This also had a seasonal dependency.
Your assumption that human labour can not run out, is thus false, it's  a very scarce resource at times.
That said, most fiat currencies are legal tender to pay taxes, tieing them to a specific economy. So in order to make your time-based currency worthwile and somewhat stable, I would suggest to make the people in your world be able (or even be forced) to spend some of their lifetime on civic duty.

Because human labor can be scarce at time, people can organize to force the scarcity and drive the price up. See labor strikes and organized "gaming" of the Uber pricing.

this is actually how many socieities did it ,, your taxes was a set amount of labor for the community as a whole.

Several ancient coinage systems worked this way
In about 500BCE, the Greek "Drachma" was a weight of silver that be sheer coincidence was worth the average day rate of a middle class worker. This lead to it becoming common practice to pay Hoplites exactly 1 Drachma per day. As it turned out, this easy relationship between salaries and weights of silver would soon become very popular.
This convenience was one of the factors that led Greek silver coinage to dominate Mediterranean trade routes; so, Emperor Darius I of the Achaemenid Empire (Persia) introduced the Daric coinage system to formally fix Persian coins to day wages. He explicitly fixed the value of his new gold coins (Darics) to the monthly salary of a common worker or soldier, and the value of his silver coins (Siglos) to the day salary of common worker or soldier.
After the Persians did this, the Greeks followed suit.  From about 500BCE through the Hellenistic Period, the day rate of hoplites remained about 1 Drachma with the size and pureness of Greek silver coins decreasing with inflation.
The Roman Denarius was another coin that was eventually fixed to a day wage.  In the Early Republic, a Denarius was worth about 3 day wages because it was based on the weight of Rome's older Bronze coins having no intended specific value; however, under Emperor Augustus, the weight, purity, and value of new Denarii were fixed to a soldier's day wage to follow suit with the ease of Greek and Persian currencies, and from that point on, Roman coins were debased every few decades (until 255AD) to keep the day value of the Denarius pretty constant throughout the Imperial period, to adjust for the rising cost of silver.
Ultimately, these systems tended to struggle when it came to foreign exchange rates, but any time you have a far flung culture, all using the same coinage, day rate coins seem just as stable as any other form of currency.

"The Roman Denarius, the Persian Siglos, the Greek Drachma, and the British Shilling were all coins based on the value of an unskilled worker's day wage": citation most definitely needed. (And all four were silver coins, made of 92.5% to 93.5% silver and the rest copper. Of course, that's before the almost complete debasement of the denary in the horrible last two centuries of the Western Roman Empire.)

@AlexP Upon further research, the British Shilling as a day wage in the late medieval period appears to have only been incidental, and not by design, but the Siglos and Denarius were expressly fixed by thier respective Emperors, and the Drachma's debasement appears to have been an attempt to keep the value fixed over time, though there were simply too many Greek states using  Drachmas to be able to say for sure how intentional or coordinated this was.

The debasement of the Denarius was definitely a coordinated effort though to keep it a day-rate coin.

During the infamous Crisis of the Third Century the denary was grossly debased to the point where it hardly contained any silver at all. It was most definitely not worth a day's wage, unless you believe that around 300 AD a worker would accept about 15 US cents (2024) for a day's labor. Eventually, as the classical world died and the Middle Ages began, the Carolingians reused the name for their new tiny silver coins, 240 to the pound, or about 1/3 of the long-forgotten early imperial denary or Attic drachm.

@AlexP You are talking about the Gallienus reforms which debased the Denarius from 45% to 0.5% silver between 255-265AD.  I'm talking about the very slow debasement between 64AD when Nero dropped it from a nearly pure 95-98% to 93.5% and all the minor debasements that followed by only a few % every few decades until 244 AD when it reached 45%.  The GDP/Capita of Rome, when measured in Denarii, remained basically unchanged from the time of Augustus until about 255AD because all the debasements up until then were efforts to rematch the value of a denarius to an average day wage.
